# Possible to use Symfony2, Doctrine2 with common entities using multiple databases in MySql and Sqlite?

Tags: sqlite, symfony, doctrine-orm, entities

I'm looking for a way of using single EntityManager with multiple databases for a MySql and sqlite connection. Mysql is used in production while we'd like to use Sqlite for tests.

It works well with mysql. I don't specify dbname in my default connection in config.yml and then reference table names in entity annotations like `@ORM\Table(name="Orders.tblAccount")`. We do this because we have cross database relationships.

But when changing the driver and using this for Sqlite i'm not able to drop / create database for this connection as there's no database name, but I don't need to specify EntityManager name to be able to use entities from different databases.

**Example: config.yml for mysql connection**

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        default_connection: Default
        connections:
            Default:
                driver:   %database_driver%
                host:     %database_host%
                user:     %database_user%
                password: %database_password%
                charset:  %database_charset%
    orm:
        default_entity_manager: Default
        entity_managers:
            Default:
                connection: Default
                mappings:
                    AcmeOrdersBundle: ~
                    AcmeStoreBundle: ~
```

**Example: annotations for entities**

```
/**
 * Acme\OrdersBundle\Entity\Account
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="Orders.tblAccount")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Acme\OrdersBundle\Repository\AccountRepository")
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 */
class Account

/**
 * Acme\OrdersBundle\Entity\AccountType
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="Orders.ublAccountType")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Acme\CoreBundle\Repository\DoctrineRepository")
 */
class AccountType extends BaseEntity

/**
 * Acme\StoreBundle\Entity\Employee
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="Store.tblEmployee")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Acme\StoreBundle\Repository\EmployeeRepository")
 */
class Employee
```

**Example: current config.yml for sqlite connection**

```
SQLite connection #config.yml

doctrine:
    dbal:
        default_connection:    Default
        connections:
            Default:
                driver:   pdo_sqlite
                path:     :memory:
                memory:   true
    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: %kernel.debug%
        auto_mapping: true
```

Entity annotations are the same, but because "." is not legal character in sqlite table names, symfony replaces it with "__". Unfortunately, it's not taken into account when querying the database, so I'm getting the following errors:

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 no such table: Store.tblEmployee

(Obviously, table created by symfony is called Store__tblEmployee)

**Question:**

Is there any way to use multiple sqlite databases on the same EntityManager? I need to be able to join across the databases, as I'm doing when connected to mysql database.

Any ideas or help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think Doctrine is not designed to manage cross-databases joins. It's possible with MySQL thanks to MySQL tolerance on table naming and db.table selection. Is it at least possible to connect to SQLite (through the SQLite client) without specifying database ?

Comment: Maybe you should define why would you use SQLite for tests (btw, what do you mean by tests?), using a different table/base/server should just be fine for either development and testing and will save you a lot of work to make it works as expected (given the little difference in SQL language support between both engine).

Comment: Note that a correct solution would be to override your `config.yml` in `config_dev.yml` and define your `connection` there.